# How to test if a variable is a Moment.js object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My application has an HTML form with some inputs populated from the backend and other inputs being entered by the user (in a `time` input). An `onChange` function runs through each input when the user changes a value.

The inputs populated from the backend are converted to `moment` objects, the user-entered dates are mere strings. This means the `onChange` function encounters some `moment` objects, and some strings. I need to know which inputs are `moment` objects and which aren't.

What's the recommended method for testing if a variable is a `moment` object?

I've noticed `moment` objects have a `_isAMomentObject` property but I'm wondering if there's another way to test if a variable is a `moment` object.

Another option I've tried is calling `moment` on the variable regardless. This converts the `string` variables to `moment` objects and doesn't seem to effect existing `moment` objects.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Moment has an [`isMoment` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-a-moment/) for just such a purpose. It is not particularly easy to find in the docs unless you know what to look for.

It first checks `instanceof` and then failing that (for instance in certain subclassing or cross-realm situations) it will test for the `_isAMomentObject` property.

Comment: what if it's not strongly typed? moment.isMoment(input);

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle this is JavaScript: there is no strong typing. 'Strong' is kind of an ambiguous term for typing, but by pretty much any possible definition (other than perhaps memory safety) JS types are weak. The only way that you can have that blow up is if `input` is `null` or `undefined`, literally any non-null JS object or even primitive value will just return a boolean.

Answer (score 40):

You can check if it is an `instanceof` moment:

```
moment() instanceof moment; // true
```

Comment: Only if the instance and moment itself are in the same window.

Comment: This is always true, because moment() would always create a moment object. Did you instead mean "obj instanceof moment;" ?

Comment: The danger of using instanceof is that the instance might be created from one moment dependency but will test against the moment function from another dependency. I.e. this will break if the code that created the moment object used another creation function than the code that tests. An example of when this can happen is if the code that runs the test above is in a separate npm package that depends on another version of moment.

Answer (score 3):

> moment() instanceof moment;

will always be true, because if you have

- moment(undefined) instanceof moment
- moment("hello") instanceof moment

you are always creating a moment object.
So the only way is to check like this

- moment(property).isValid()

Comment: I think you meant to make a *comment* to Niels' answer.

Answer (score 0):

While technically all upvoted responses are true and are the way to go, in my particular case @Anang Sartia's answer worked.

I had a Shared packages library and two downstream apps that were importing the package library. One downstream app migrated from MomentJS to Date-FNS (that works with plain JS Date objects), while the other still remained with Moment. The reason to migrate from Moment was primarily due to large bundle size and the fact that MomentJS doesn't suport tree-shaking (and other disadvantages provided by MomentJS team here [https://momentjs.com/#:~:text=Considering%20using%20Moment,in%20the%20docs](https://momentjs.com/#:%7E:text=Considering%20using%20Moment,in%20the%20docs).

The Shared packages had a method that was transforming plain objects. Dates were not falling into that criteria. So because Dates and Moment are also objects, they had to be ignored. Using `moment.isMoment(obj)` implied that Shared packages also need to install Moment.JS just to check for this particular case. And because `Moment.JS` is not tree-shakable, it was not a great idea to import moment just for a single moment method.

In my case I created a helper method that checks for `_isAMomentObject` property.  `isValid` property remarked by @Anang Satria could be present in any regular object. On the other hand, any valid Moment object has this unique property `_isAMomentObject`. Doing so, in my case solved the issue.

```
export function isMomentObject(obj: any): boolean {
  return !!obj._isAMomentObject;
}
```

***To summarize:***

If you already have defined MomentJS as the dependency then `moment.isMoment(obj)` is the way to go.
If you don't want to import moment, but somehow you get Moment objects and you want to treat them differently, then you should consider the provided alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty similar to the answer by @Fabien, I'm checking the object if the `isValid` function is available.

```
const checkMoment = (date) => {
    if(!date.isValid){ // check if it's not a moment object
        // do something if it's not moment object
        console.log('this is not a moment object');
    }
    else {
        // do something if it's a moment object
        console.log('this is a moment object');
    }
   
}
```